# Reuse single ViewModel with multiple fragments. MvvmCross Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I'm newbie with MvvmCross. I'm developing an app using Mvx v6.0.1.
I want to make a kind of stepper using fragments (specifically 4 fragments or 4 steps), all of these fragments are embedded into an main activity. The main activity layout has a button, when I tap these button fragment is switched to the next step. I have created one viewmodel for each fragment and one more for the main activity. The problem I have is that I need to get some values from each step and pass to the next step.
I'm trying to share only one viewmodel for every view (fragments and activity). Is there any way to achieve this?

If yes, How can I distinguish each steps/fragments for navigate across them?

I was trying to set same viewmodel to Activity and fragment:

```
   //Activity code
   public class AttendanceActivity : BaseActivity<AttendanceViewModel>
   {
       protected override int ActivityLayoutId => Resource.Layout.activity_attendance;

       //some logic
   }

   //Fragment code
   [MvxFragmentPresentation(ActivityHostViewModelType = typeof(AttendanceViewModel),
    FragmentContentId = Resource.Id.attendance_content_frame,
    AddToBackStack = true)]
    public class AttendanceFragmentSetpOne : BaseFragment<AttendanceViewModel>, IOnClickListener
    {
        protected override int FragmentLayoutId => Resource.Layout.fragment_attendance_step_one;

        //Some logic
    }
```

But when I make this, the app never pass from splash screen.

I hope explain myself and somebody help me with this "problem".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello, can't understand the steps in `4 fragments or 4 steps`

Comment: Oh, that is because each step of my app is one fragment with its own layout.

Comment: basically I start the app on "Step 1" (fragment one), then I have to capture some values. When I tap a button inside this view, I have to navigate to the "Step 2" view (fragment two) and pass the values captured (since step one to step two),  this behavior is the same for 4 steps.

Comment: Hello, have you solved it?

Comment: Hi, I didn't found any sample nor possible solution for that. I was reading about MvvmCross Facades and I think that it is my best option, but sincerely I haven't test it yet.